# Send a sequence of commands to a new terminal from a script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a script to which I wanna add a shutdown timer at the end, I'd like the countdown to run in a new terminal windows so I can cancel it since the script will usually be run in the background.

Here's the problem,

a simple script containing only the following

```
secs=$((60))
while [ $secs -gt 0 ]; do
   echo -ne "$secs\033[0K\r"
   sleep 1
   : $((secs--))
done
shutdown now
```

works fine, but if I try to send it to a new terminal like this

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c
'secs=$((60))
while [ $secs -gt 0 ]; do
   echo -ne \"$secs\033[0K\r\"
   sleep 1
   : $((secs--))
done
shutdown now'"
```

it fails and just shuts down. If I remove the shutdown line I get this error :

```
Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

thanks

Comment: `secs=$((60))` does the exact same thing as `secs=60`. Yes, it creates an arithmetic expression -- but at assignment time, the value is still stored as a string either way.

Comment: Also, `echo -e` not only *undefined* by the POSIX standard for `echo`, but actually *illegal*, in that the only thing a compliant shell is allowed to do when run as `echo -e` is print a line with the string `-e`. See [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), noting the OPTIONS section ("Implementations shall not support any options"); `-n` being specified to make behavior implementation-defined (thus, outside the standard); and the APPLICATION USAGE section indicating that `printf` should be used instead for new development.

Comment: ...while bash behaves in a manner contrary to the standard out-of-the-box, if `posix` and `xpg_echo` flags are set (which can be made default via either compile-time options or appropriate environment variables, in addition to configuration with `shopt` and `set`), its `echo` implementation will become strictly conformant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to export a function:

```
countdown() {
  secs=60
  while (( secs > 0 )); do
     printf '%s\033[0K\r' "$secs"
     sleep 1
     ((secs--))
  done
  shutdown now
}
export -f countdown

gnome-terminal -- bash -c countdown
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Makes a lot of sense, I really appreciate your help :)