# Open a terminal via gnome-terminal then execute command, error : "failed to execute child process""

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

Via a bash command, I want open a terminal and, from the new terminal, execute a simple bash command.

I tried:

```
gnome-terminal -- "/bin/bash -c ls"
```

But I got this error:

[image]

I don't understand the error and I cannot find an example anywhere for help.

Comment: Use the `-e` option. It's taking that command as the name of a program to run, not a shell command to execute.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: -e arg is deprecied :/ ('Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.'). Nothing work when I use -e option, I get just the "deprecated" message

Comment: `gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c ls`. No quotes.

Comment: nothing happen when I don't use quotes, no error, no new terminal, nothing

Comment: Probably because it's exiting immediately. Try instead, say, `gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c 'ls; sleep 3'`

Comment: BTW, this has already been asked and answered here before. Give me a minute to find the duplicate to close the question...

Comment: hannn your right ! its work ! is there a way for 'keep' alive the new terminal after the command ?

Comment: Give it any command that waits indefinitely without exit.

Comment: ok =) thank you a lot !

Comment: Ahh -- the other question I was thinking about was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236537/send-a-sequence-of-commands-to-a-new-terminal-from-a-script, but while the answer covers some similar ground, it's not quite a duplicate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The quotes are telling the terminal to run an executable in `/bin` called `bash -c ls` (with the spaces as part of its name!). There exists no such executable.

Take them out:

```
gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c ls
```

...or, to actually make something stay open until the user provides input...

```
gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c 'ls; read'
```

Comment: thank you :) as I ask from comment , is there a way for keep alive the new terminal regardless the command executed ?

Comment: On a GNU system, you could run `sleep infinity` as the final command. More portably, though, I'd expect that `sleep $(( 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 ))` (to sleep for a year) would probably be good enough.

Comment: You can try gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c 'ls;exec /bin/bash'