# unable to open file '/etc/dconf/db/local' error when using gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

I am simply trying to run a command in a new terminal window. Based on my reading it seems that the following command should work

```
gnome-terminal -- "ls"
```

But I get the following error message:

```
# unable to open file '/etc/dconf/db/local': Failed to open file “/etc/dconf/db/local”: open() failed: No such file or directory; expect degraded performance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Open a terminal via gnome-terminal then execute command, error : "failed to execute child process""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627989/open-a-terminal-via-gnome-terminal-then-execute-command-error-failed-to-exec)

```
gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c ls
```